# How to find element by xpath in shadow dom

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, shadow, shadow-dom

[image]

I have tried the below code for element "Loading History". But not working. Please help to solve by Xpath

```
  seleniumlib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance('SeleniumLibrary')
  driver = seleniumlib.driver
  root1 = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('sn-component-va-web-client')
  shadow_root1 = expand_shadow_element(driver,root1)
  shadow_root1.find_element_by_xpath("//div[text()='Loading History']")
```

Comment: can you provide the full source code because we need to track from the beginning

Comment: refer this [Link](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/accessing-shadow-dom-elements-with-webdriver)

Comment: Please define "not working" - is there an error thrown, and at which line?

Comment: Update the question a bit more of the outerHTML